# How do I figure out how to count files with 'no extention' seperately

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Some files dont have an extention at all and i need to figure how to count them as "no extention" types

```
import os
extension_count = {}
# no_extention_count = {}
for filename in os.listdir('/Users/saraAlbertt/Downloads'):
    pieces = filename.split('.')
    # print(pieces)
    extension = pieces[-1]
    # print(extension)
    if extension not in extension_count:
        extension_count[extension] = 1
    else:
        extension_count[extension] += 1
```

pieces are lists in my files that are split into strings and some have extentions which is the last element in the list. All lists have different sizes and i need to figure out how to not count lists with only one element inside as extention.

{'dmg': 2, 'png': 6, 'MP4': 3, 'vtt': 4, 'docx': 12, 'DS_Store': 1, 'dots-game': 1, 'localized': 1, 'download': 1, 'pptx': 2, 'pkg': 1, 'txt': 4, 'World': 1, 'JPEG': 1, 'crdownload': 3, 'm4a': 1, 'app': 1, 'ppt': 1, 'jpg': 2, 'zip': 2, 'mp4': 1}

this is the outcome of printing (extention_count) but some files like Ds-store are not extentions and look like this ['DS-store']
I want to minus extention from pieces to get the no-extention and if the length equals to 1 count it seperately as no_extention_count = {}

Comment: You could check if after the split neither side is empty using `if not left` to verify it's not a filename starting with a dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `os.path.splitext`, stripping a leading dot and checking for an empty extension will do the trick:

```py
import os

extension_count = {}
no_extension_count = 0
for filename in os.listdir('/Users/saraAlbertt/Downloads'):
    _, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if not extension:
        no_extension_count += 1
    else:
        extension = extension.lstrip('.')
        if extension not in extension_count:
            extension_count[extension] = 1
        else:
            extension_count[extension] += 1
```

Comment: Thankyou this worked but what if i wanted those files to go to no_extension_count instead of extension_count because currently 'no extention' is 'no extention: 4' but inside extention_count

Comment: @Sara_learningToCode thank you for accepting my answer. I updated it so the filenames without an extension increment a separate `int no_extension_count`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
extension_count = {}
no_extension_count = 0

for filename in os.listdir('/Users/saraAlbertt/Downloads'):
    pieces = filename.split('.')
    # print(pieces)
    
    # If a file had an extension, pieces would equal 2.
    # This only works if you are sure that filenames do not include dots
    if len(pieces) == 1: 
        no_extention_count += 1
        continue

    extension = pieces[-1]
    # print(extension)
    if extension not in extension_count:
        extension_count[extension] = 1
    else:
        extension_count[extension] += 1
```

Comment: Elegant logic on this if condition, nice thinking

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking look at [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) function, which does return pair of *(root, ext)*, latter is empty string in case *path contains no extension*, consider following simple example

```
import collections
import os
files = ['file.mp4','file.txt','file']
count = collections.defaultdict(int)
for f in files:
    count[os.path.splitext(f)[-1]] += 1
print(dict(count))
```

gives output

```
{'.mp4': 1, '.txt': 1, '': 1}
```

Observe that I have used [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which allows me to increase value by 1 without prior checking if it does exist or not.

Comment: Would this also solve the problematic cases described by OP, such as `.DS_Store`?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I do run test in my python (3.8) and `os.path.splitext(".DS_Store")` gives `('.DS_Store', '')` that is it does consider `.DS_Store` to have empty extension. I do not know if it will work this way in all python versions in all operating systems.

Comment: I like this solution then. Really short and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple if check to check the length of `pieces`, such as:

```py
if len(pieces) == 1:
   ##Add To "No Extension"
else:
   ##Add to Associated Extension
```

This should check whether or not the file has an extension. You could alternatively check `filename` for "." before you split it with :

```py
if "." not in filename:
   ###Add to "No extension"
```

Either of those should work.

Answer (score 0):

`str.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)` method returns list whether length is one(no extension) or two(has extension).

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.system('ls /var/log')
alternatives.log
apt
btmp
dpkg.log
faillog
fontconfig.log
lastlog
wtmp
0

>>> from collections import defaultdict
...
... extension_count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
... no_extension_count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
...
... for filename in os.listdir('/var/log'):
...     filename_n_ext = filename.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)
...     if len(filename_n_ext) == 1:
...         no_extension_count[filename_n_ext[0]] += 1
...     else:  # len(filename_n_ext) == 2
...         extension_count[filename_n_ext[1]] += 1

>>> no_extension_count
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f33d4d90ee0>, {'faillog': 1, 'apt': 1, 'wtmp': 1, 'lastlog': 1, 'btmp': 1})
>>> extension_count
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f33d4d90e50>, {'log': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let `Counter` from `collections` do the hard work for you, in only one line of code.

```
import os
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(list(map(lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1], os.listdir('path/here'))))

print(c)
Counter({'.py': 14, '.html': 5, '': 5, '.csv': 3})
```

From this you can see the number with no extension (from the key of '').